# MSAccess database with Basic - accessing fields

Tags: ms-access, vba

First time I'm touching both access and basic, but I'm doing a favor for my sister.
I have to retrieve data from a table and some headings have a % character in them and changing the headings is not and option. what does msaccess replace % with?

Let Entitlement = rc![Entitlement% pozitia 1]

rc is the recordset :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no Access db handy to test at the moment,
but you might try displaying the field names: (code from [here](http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=2856))

```
Public Sub GetTableObjects()
   Dim db As Database
   Dim tbl As TableDef
   Dim Fld As Field
   Set db = CurrentDb
   For Each tbl In db.TableDefs
     Debug.Print "Table: " & tbl.Name & " ***"
       For Each Fld In tbl.Fields
         Debug.Print Fld.Name
       Next Fld
   Next tbl
End Sub
```

Comment: Cheers mate.  It may be a pain in the neck, but it's good of you to help your sister!  I forgot to upvote your question earlier, but just did now.